# Creating Objects with new in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to understand a piece of code that I ran into in an example that creates pointers to new objects using the following syntax:

MyClass *p (new MyClass);

I can't find this style of syntax in any other reference source that I have and I was wondering if you could let me know why it works and if this syntax creates object that are different than the object created by the following. I have always done this like:

MyClass *p = new Myclass;

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Constructor Initialization* encloses the initial value *new myClass* in the created object `myClass *p`.

Both `myClass *p (new myClass)` AND `myClass *p = new myClass` are essentially the same thing - they initialize an Object pointer p and assign it as a new Object referencing myClass.